Firebase Analytics - не отображается новая версия приложения
Выкатили новую версию приложения - 1.1.0
Но в Analytics Dashboard релизная версия до сих пор осталась прежняя - 1.0.2.
При этом в Cryshlytics и Release Monitoring актуальная версия отображается.
Обновление google-service.json проблему не решило.
В чем может быть проблема?
